# In Django, how can I run a function in background

Tags: python, django, multithreading, background-process

I want to send email through `send_mail()` in Django to all the users in a table when I publish my article. I want to know how can I do this job by calling another function from my article publish function which can perform this task in background or in another thread so that my publish function can publish an article and the function which was called to send email can perform the task in background.

Comment: this is a very common question and can be easily answered by search your answer in the search engine. Anyway, your question is very generic.

Comment: This question is way too broad and is unanswerable in its current state.

Comment: Just to help you out, There are multiple ways, one of them is to use a separate processing app, such as celery. and you will have to send the task to them via a broker. checkout celery for more info

Comment: Celery will work, but its not exactly a lightweight set up. Does the task actually need to be run in the background? I send emails when saving forms, and the performance doesn't suffer noticably.

Comment: @wobbily_col, I have to send emails to hundreds of subscribers. If I include the send_mail() in my function will the server not take time to send emails to all the people and then show that my post is published ?

Comment: Emails don't take long to send. The obvious thing to do would be to try it and see how long it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, by creating a custom HttpResponse-object:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

# use custom response class to override HttpResponse.close()
class HttpResponseAndMail(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, article="", people=[], *args, **kwargs):
        super(HttpResponseAndMail, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.article = article
        self.people = people

    def close(self):
        super(HttpResponseAndMail, self).close()
        # do whatever you want, this is the last codepoint in request handling
        if self.status_code == 200:
            send_mail(subject="", from_email="", message=self.article, recipient_list=self.people)
```

This code is run in the same python thread, but only after everything else is finished, thus not slowing down your web-server.